# How to delete the remote Git branch via the Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, remote-branch

I want to delete the remote branch in Visual Studio Code but it seems like it's not supported.

GitLens supports **Delete Branch (via Terminal)** but I want to do it from the Command Palette.

I tried finding the extension but couldn't find one.

Can anyone suggest how can I delete remote branches via the command palette in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to do it from Command Palette.
>   Tried finding the extension but couldn't find one.

Currently, as shown in [vscode-gitlens issue 385](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/385), this is done only though terminal:

> - Go to Source Control view (Ctrl + Shift + G) and expand the GITLENS section in the sidebar
> - Find branch to delete under Remotes (e.g. geolocation)
> - Right click on branch and choose Delete Branch (via Terminal)
>
> Text entered into terminal reads: `git push origin :aRemoteBranch`

That remains (Q1 2019) the official way to delete a remote branch.